# How to extract a broken 6.5mm plug from jack?

Tags: tools

One of my 6.5mm adapter was broken and the heading pieces was kept in the jack. (picture atatched) What tool should I use to extract the broken part?

[image]

Comment: use your imagination

Answer (score 2):

Best option is to open the device and use a tool or paperclip to push the remains out.

Does depend on having access though, or very fine tweezers but then you tend to be working blind...

Whatever you try, remove the battery or disconnect power first and wait 30 minutes for caps to discharge.